# How can I upgrade the SVN version used by git svn in Windows?

Tags: git, version, git-svn, upgrade

My company is in the process of upgrading SVN to 1.7.  Checking `git svn --version` shows that the SVN version being used is 1.4.6.  I'd like to get the version of SVN that git svn uses up closer to 1.7.  However, I've seen no instructions for updating the version of SVN that git svn uses (in Windows).

The [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341159/how-to-upgrade-the-svn-version-used-by-git-svn) I found looking for answers seems to be oriented to a Mac OSX user.  I haven't seen Windows instructions for this upgrade, however.  Does anyone know how to properly update the SVN version for git svn in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using mSysGit on Windows, since I'm using a recent install and `git svn --version` is also listing v1.4.6 for me.

The reason you've seen no instructions is that you're using the latest version of mSysGit. You can't upgrade if there's nothing to upgrade to! You've a few options:

- Don't bother. Everything will just work as it always has, since a Subversion 1.7 server will happily work with an older client. Continuing to use your version of `git svn` will cause no more issues than it does at present, if it causes any at all.
- Use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). The Subversion version that `git svn` on Cygwin uses is 1.7.4.
- Wait for a new version to come out. Given mSysGit is still at Subversion 1.4.6, I wouldn't hold much hope for this happening any time soon.

Comment: Time to dust off Cygwin, I guess...  Thanks for the info.

Comment: That's a shame. Cygwin's newest version apparently doesn't play nicely with git (specifically gitk...which I'd like to have the use of).  At least, not out of the box.  This will take some tinkering.  Either way, good call on Cygwin.  Perhaps I'll try to find an older version.

Comment: @MattD: Ahaha. Been there, done that, ranted at the Cygwin mailing list about it. See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9418800/220155) for how to get gitk working. It's fairly simple, but not documented anywhere sensible. (That question's about Git GUI, but it's the same underlying problem.)

Comment: Very much appreciated.  I'm pretty sure I tried steps along the same line, but I will definitely give your specific instructions a shot and see if I can get it working.  It's pretty disappointing that this issue came up.  I would really prefer to use Cygwin over a dedicated git bash which I'm currently using (for more reasons than just the git-svn version).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with git1.7.8 (October 2012), `git svn` will officially work with SVN1.7

See "[[ANNOUNCE] Git v1.8.0-rc3](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/ANNOUNCE-Git-v1-8-0-rc3-td7569466.html)":

> "`git svn`" has been updated to work with SVN 1.7.

Comment: Unfortunately git 1.8.1.2 doesn't seem to have this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the version of git that I installed from GitHub (http://windows.github.com/) had svn 1.7 but mSysGit 1.8.1.2 still had svn 1.4.

On further inspection I noticed that GitHub for Windows doesn't ship with svn! It turns out that it was picking up my command line version of svn that I had installed in Windows separately.

Deleting all the svn* files from the mSysGit/bin directory had the same effect. It will pick up whatever version of svn you have installed in Windows (assuming that it is on the PATH).