# msysgit: svn client to old, how to upgrade the client or point git to use the installed svn client

Tags: git, svn, msysgit

I have just installed git from http://msysgit.github.io/ and checked the git svn version. The version is 1.4.6. On the other hand I have an svn client installed that is on version 1.7.10.
I have been searching now for more than an hour on how to update the git svn client or to let msysgit use the already installed svn client (version 1.7.10). Can anyone point me to a solution?

Added note:

I have looked into it once more and I found in `libexec/git-core` the perl script `git-svn`. I guess this will lead to a solution of my problem, but since I am not familiar with perl I hesitate to do anything here.

Finally I want to note what I have found on the [msysgit FAQ page](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) that it seems to be by far not trivial to solve my problem. The msysgit developers would be happy to find a passionate developer to solve the problem.

Comment: this is not probably an answer but if you check the change log for git 1.8.0 here . https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt There is a line that says. `"git svn" has been updated to work with SVN 1.7.` so that should work.

Comment: or check out an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695303/how-can-i-upgrade-the-svn-version-used-by-git-svn-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use SubGit (http://subgit.com)?

You may configure interim Git repository to mirror your Subversion project and then just use Git.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of SubGit.

Comment: I have the problem that the svn repo is not under my control and when you look at this [link](http://blog.tfnico.com/2011/12/git-svn-mirror-product-subgit.html) you see that this is a most and it is not adviced to use it in a professional environment, i.e. with hundreds of developers.

Comment: @FrankZimmer this post of Thomas is two years old and is no longer relevant. Since version 2.0 SubGit works in 'remote' mode, i.e. with Subversion repositories that are not under your control, and no instrumentation is required. 

I am SubGit developer and there are huge repositories with more than 100 of devs maintained by SubGit. Would you need assistance with SubGit or more questions you may contact us at support@subgit.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly set your PATH variable. For example say you have 1.4.6 installed at `/bin` and 1.7.10 installed at `/usr/local/bin`, you could add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin
```

Or, if you want to just get rid of the of version you could do

```
rm /bin/svn
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work yet. It seems so that if I type git svn --version the msysgit installation seems to take its information from the libsvn_client-1-0.dll (this is a guess) and doesn't really care about the path variable. If I move all dlls in msysgit's bin folder to another place and try the same I get an error message coming from the underlying perl implementation.